# Taking line count of individual files in an HDFS directory

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I want to take line count of individual files (along with the file names) of a directory in HDFS, the output should be similar to this :

```
4 filename_1.txt
20 filename_2.txt
8 filename_3.txt
```

Currently I'm using

hadoop fs -cat /user/TMM/ | wc -l

which is giving the total count of the directory. (In this case eg : 32 )

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the shell script , please refer the below snippet that could help you.

```
for i in $( hadoop fs -ls <hdfs-path> | tr -s ' ' | grep '/' | awk '{print$8}');
   do
      echo $i `hadoop fs -cat $i | wc -l`;
   done;
```

This will print every file under the `hdfs-path` along with the line count.

[Note : the file name was printed at 8 index in the `hadoop fs -ls` output from my hadoop version, check it in your environment accordingly]

Answer (score 0):

If your amount of data is small enough you can do that, but that approach imply to transfer all data from your HDFS custer to a client machine. Not good.

An alternative is create a MapReduce job. Get the filename from the context (getInputSplit) and emmit one event for each input line where the key could be the filename and the value could be 1. Better if you create a local aggregation in the map to avoid transfer a lot of objects to the reducer. In the reducer complete the aggregation and write the output to a file in HDFS.